# Mouseleave and MouseOut Fire Twice in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to use the mouseleave function for one of my divs.  I've attached two different fiddles, one using jquery and the other using plain javascript.  The jquery example uses (document).on because the div and all the data inside of it are generated via an Ajax call.  Both fiddles work fine in Chrome, however, when opened in Internet Explorer, the alert box fires twice.  Interestingly, if you change the alert box to a console.log() in Internet Explorer, it only writes to the console once.

Anyone come across this before?  The desired behavior is for the alert box to fire a single time in Internet Explorer when the mouse leaves the div.

https://jsfiddle.net/ttu1ouvz/

```
<div id="myTestDiv">
  <p>
     testing 
  </p>
</div>

$(document).on("mouseleave", "#myTestDiv", function() {
    alert("Your hovered over the test div");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ttu1ouvz/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="myTestDiv" onmouseout="mouseLeft(this)">
  <p>
     testing 
  </p>
</div>

<script>
function mouseLeft(x){
        alert("Your left the test div");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue using [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/);

```
$(document).hover(function(){
    alert("Your hovered over the test div");
}, function(){
    alert("Your mouse leave from the test div");
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/hover/
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp

Comment: I tried using the code in IE, but it still generates 2 popup messages when leaving the div.  See this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/ttu1ouvz/5/